# How to Control for longer term trends in an asset against an intraday strategy?

Tags: strategy, intraday

Say I have a simple S&P500 intraday strategy that buys at open, close at noon.

What are some good methods for controlling for the fact that the S&P500 tends to move higher over the long term and this strategy has a long bias?

Another example: Buy Gold at 9:30AM and flatten at Noon.

How would you control for the fact that gold has had an upwards trend over the last 10 years?

Comment: There are many ways, but none is completely satisfactory to me. The simplest is to consider 2 strategies: your trading strategy and a Buy and Hold strategy that is constantly long 1 future (rolling to a new contract if necessary). What is the historical P&L and risk (std dev, drawdown, etc.) of these 2 strategies over the time horizon of interest? Which do you prefer?

Comment: I supposed you can regress the intraday returns against daily returns and see if there is an alpha. Yes, you approach would be a first step, but I'd like to find something a bit more robust.

Comment: Speaking of regression, another method I like is the Cumby-Modest test of market timing. Essentially you regress market returns in various periods on a 0/1 variable which is 1 if your strategy is long during the time period and 0 if your startegy is flat. The significance of this regression is then examined. For details see the article in JFE 1987.

Comment: That makes sense.